# crontab not running script

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I am trying to run a script from crontab and it doesn't work. but when i run it from command line it does. I understand that the env might be affecting it, but i can't seem to figure out what it is that is different that is stopping it from working - tried user crontab and sudo crontab. can any one point me in the right direction please.

Sudo cron env

```
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/root
```

User cron env

```
HOME=/home/pi
LOGNAME=pi
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/home/pi
```

User env

```
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.4.4 50682 192.168.4.1 22
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
XDG_SESSION_ID=c15
USER=pi
PWD=/home/pi/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples
HOME=/home/pi
TEXTDOMAIN=Linux-PAM
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.4.4 50682 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
MAIL=/var/mail/pi
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHLVL=1
LOGNAME=pi
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
OLDPWD=/home/pi
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Script to be called by cron

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
PWD=/home/pi

gphoto2 --auto-detect --capture-image-and-download --filename /home/pi/plywood/%d-%m-%y_%H-%M.jpg &>> /home/pi/ercamaera.log
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd guess that `gphoto2` is an x application? In which case you'll need an X sesison open and `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` set appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. gphoto2 is a command line tool, that is the backend fro some GUI tools

Comment: Have you maybe considered looking at your log file?

Comment: I have checked syslog and couldn't find anything that I thought was pertinent. I didn't think Cron had its own log file and it went under syslog, is that incorrect?

Comment: Can you add the output of `crontab -l` ? You need a line like `* * * * * /path/script`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cron called a script which had % symbols in it and unfortunately caused issues. I changed how I was dating the file name by

```
DATE = (date +"%d-%m-%y_%H-%M")
```

And referenced this in the file naming

```
/home/pi/$DATE.jpg
```

This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try `crontab -e` when logged in as the user you want the cron job setup for.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I probably didn't explain very well in my initial question. I have tried to run the script under sudo crontab -e and also user profile as crontab -e to no avail.

Comment: Ok! wasn't sure. I have run into the same problem by not using `crontab -e` before..Anyhow, have you tried trapping and script error that occur and dumping to `/tmp/script.out` file or something...More on trapping errors in a bash script here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39623/trap-err-and-echoing-the-error-line